# Combining two strings for a label's text

Tags: objective-c

Real beginners question here. I'm doing some tutorials and I'm expanding on them with scenarios that might come in to play.

Anyhow, I know that the following works:

```
lblCopyStatus.text = @"Test";
```

But how would do:

```
lblCopyStatus.text = @"Test" & lbltest.text;
```

e.g. get the text from another label into the text. I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: What do you mean to achieve by bitwise-AND-ing the two pointers?

Comment: He/She maybe want's to append text? - educated guess.

Comment: I have text in lbltest.text that I also want visible in lblcopystatus.text (upon a button click). I'm really new so sorry if I'm not making much sense.

Comment: @Bushell Two pieces of good advice for a beginner: 1. http://developer.apple.com and http://google.com are **with no exception** to be searched before posting on Stack Overflow. 2. You may want to start with learning C well before getting your hands on iOS development. (Basically, if you don't know C already, you'll regret it and/or you'll learn and get used to some seriously bad concepts/practice.)

Comment: What information have you gleaned while researching this problem? What possible solutions were suggested by that information? What wasn't clear or didn't work? In short, what have you tried?

Comment: This is the exact same problem as the question you asked the other day! [Setting a cell's text with multiple JSON objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16222531)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
lblCopyStatus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %@", lbltest.text];
```

Comment: Also, `t1 = [@"Test " stringByAppendingString:t2];` to avoid format string overuse.

Comment: More information on string formats in Objective-C: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html